# What should be the minimum length of historical data used for analysis?

Tags: historical-data

What should be the minimal length of historical data to do "practical" portfolio analysis to achieve "sane" results?

There are several questions here on what should be done when a portfolio historical data is not symmetrical (stock A has 10 years of data and stock B just one year). There are several approaches and one of them is to use the slice equal to the smallest constituent.

What is the general consensus on what the length of that slice should be?

I put practical and sane in quotations, because:

1. You can use 2 data points and it will yield some kind of result.
2. Right now i do not want to engage in scientific approaches of extrapolating data, which definitely can be done, rather I would like to do a quick and dirty analysis.

Links to research papers would be great as well.

Comment: For  what kind of analysis? For a Markowitz style optimization based on risk and return? Or for estimation of risk  parameters (Beta, VaR, etc.) ?

Comment: @noob2 Yes, MVO for example.